# Xcode is not opening

Tags: osx-lion, xcode

I'm pretty newbie on Mac.

I wanna open Xcode, when I clink on the icon, nothing happens, not a warning or error, the icon jumps a little bit then stops and thats it, no Xcode or loading screen etc. I can see the Xcode icon when I hit Command-Tab, but again when I click that Icon, nothing happens.

As if it is already opened but cannot be accessed for some reason.

Since I am a newbie in Mac, I dont know how to try to find the error(if any), or try to debug it. How should I approach the problem.

(Should I uninstall and reinstall like good old windows)

Version is Mac OS X 10.7.3

Comment: Do you have the latest version of XCode from the Mac App Store? A new one is released every time OS X has a point release.

Comment: @Randolph West yes, i just bought the mac and updated to the last version of everything.

Comment: This isn't what I'd do, but if all else fails, here's how to uninstall it. Maybe that'll work: http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2011/08/29/how-to-uninstall-xcode-from-mac-app-store/

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Looks like the welcome screen is hidden.
Click on: **Window** -> **Welcome to Xcode**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM65z.png)